# Which URLs does Maven resolve with a subpath in child POMs?

Tags: java, maven

I read somewhere that if a Maven project uses inheritance, then its child projects will automatically add a subpath to the URL using the child projects's `artifactId`. But now I can't find the reference.

Which inherited URLs will Maven inherit verbatim from the parent POM, and to which will it add a subpath for the child POM? For example, here are a few URLs I could find:

- `<project><url>`
- `<project><scm><url>`
- `<project><distributionManagement><site><url>`

Maybe I'm mistaken and none of them add a subpath, but I have it in my notes. Unfortunately I can't seem to find a definitive answer using Internet searches.

Please try to provide an authoritative reference in your answer. (Of course if there is no documentation on this, direct testing will be second best.) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of these elements are defined in the [maven XSD schema](https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd) which is properly documented (`xs:documentation` tags).

Here's the documentation for urls:

`project.url` (line 102):

> The URL to the project's homepage.
>   **Default value is:** parent value [+ path adjustment] + (artifactId or project.directory property)

Path adjustment only applies when the path to a child project doesn't match its artifactid.

`project.directory` is a property and you can override it in the [`properties`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) tag.

`site.url` (line 544):

> The url of the location where website is deployed, in the form `protocol://hostname/path`. 
> **Default value is**: parent value [+ path adjustment] + artifactId

`scm.url` (line 823):

> The URL to the project's browsable SCM repository, such as ViewVC or Fisheye. 
> **Default value is**: parent value [+ path adjustment] + artifactId

So, the default value for all of these elements includes both path adjustment and artifactId.

There're several other elements named `url`. Not all of them are path adjusted, e.g. the url of a repository is not.

### Example

Let's create an example that covers all of the options above.

For this example, we'll need a project (`maven-urls`) with three modules:

- `child-project` - a regular submodule that doesn't override anything.
- `child-with-a-project-directory` - a submodule that declares a `project.directory` property.
- `path-adjusted-child` - a submodule that has an unexpected relative path.

. The directory structure should look like this:

```
maven-urls
    child-project
    child-with-a-project-directory
    path
        path-adjusted-child
```

**Parent project pom**

Here we'll declare three different urls and child projects (note the path to `path-adjusted-child`):

```
...
<url>https://example.com</url>
<scm>
    <url>https://example.com/scm</url>
</scm>
<modules>
    <module>child-project</module>
    <module>path/path-adjusted-child</module>
    <module>child-with-a-project-directory</module>
</modules>
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <url>https://example.com/distribution</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
...
```

**Project directory**

For a `child-with-a-project-directory` we'll set a `project.directory` property

```
...
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.directory>project</project.directory>
</properties>
...
```

**Path-adjusted project**

A path-adjusted project needs to declare a relative path to the parent module:

```
...
<parent>
    ...
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
...
```

You can check out the full code on github: https://github.com/defaultlocale/maven-urls.

### Results

Now we can build the whole project and check the values. We can use maven help plugin and it's [`effective-pom`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) goal to find the effective URLs for each of the child projects.

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

Here's the output for all of them:

**`child-project`:**

```
<url>https://example.com/child-project</url>
<scm>
    <url>https://example.com/scm/child-project</url>
</scm>
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <url>https://example.com/distribution/child-project</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
```

Nothing unexpected here. Every URLs is just a parent URL with an `artifactId` attached.

**`child-with-a-project-directory`:**

```
...
<url>https://example.com/project</url>
<scm>
    <url>https://example.com/scm/project</url>
</scm>
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <url>https://example.com/distribution/project</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
...
```

As it turns out, `project.directory` overrides `artifactId` for all three URLs. This is unexpected and is not covered in the documentation.

**`path-adjusted-child`:**

```
<url>https://example.com/path/path-adjusted-child</url>
<scm>
    <url>https://example.com/scm/path/path-adjusted-child</url>
</scm>
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <url>https://example.com/distribution/path/path-adjusted-child</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
...
```

No surprises here every url includes a relative path and artifactId.

Comment: Very useful. Note that a more readable version is found at https://maven.apache.org/maven-model/maven.html . Do you happen to know where "path adjustment" is defined/described?

Comment: Wow, so does this mean that if I have a multiple-project repository, where each subproject/module is being published to Maven Central, then I have to include the `<scm><url>` information in each child POM or they will wind up with incorrect source code repository information?

Comment: Note that https://maven.apache.org/maven-model/maven.html indicates that the `project.directory` may be used instead of `artifactId`. Is this set automatically, or simply something I can specify to override this value? Where does it come from?

Comment: And why is `[+ path adjustment]` in square brackets, as if it's optional? I would assume `parent value` is optional, too; do the brackets imply some special conditions? What conditions?

Comment: @GarretWilson Yeah, more readable version reference version 3.5.3 of a schema. For some reason, I couldn't find a similar documentation page for the latest version. That's why I decided to link to an XSD.

Comment: @GarretWilson All good questions :) I've updated my answer with additional explanations. I also created an example to demonstrate the different combinations of POM settings. See if it helps.

Comment: A tiny clarification: You mention, "This is unexpected and is not covered in the documentation." But it is explicitly mentioned at https://maven.apache.org/maven-model/maven.html , just not in the XSD you indicated.

Comment: This answer is wonderful! Thank you for all the time you put into this; I think a lot of people will find it helpful.

Comment: @GarretWilson You're welcome! Thank you for telling me about the docs, there seems to be a discrepancy. Will fix my answer later. Good luck!