# How does nexus-staging-maven-plugin use <scm> information?

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I have a single Git repository that contains several Maven modules, using Maven inheritance and Maven aggregation. That is, in the root directory, there is a parent POM, that defines some modules, each of which use that root POM as their parent.

```
<project>
  …
  <groupId>io.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  …
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://bitbucket.org/example/foobar.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://bitbucket.org/example/foobar.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://bitbucket.org/example/foobar</url>
  </scm>
  …
  <modules>
    <module>foo</module>
    <module>bar</module>
  </modules>
  …
```

I recently [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50361963/421049) that Maven will append the module path to the `<scm><url>` value for each module (`foo` and `bar` above). For example, the `foo` submodule would get an SCM URL of `https://bitbucket.org/example/foobar/foo`.

So should each of my modules *redeclare* the `<scm>` section, so that the submodule POMs have the same SCM URL as the parent POM? How does the Nexus Staging Maven Plugin use this SCM information, anyway?

I have also cross-posted this [at Sonatype](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-3437).

Comment: Simple answer: Only define the scm information in the root module of your modules. Furthermore as far as I know the nexus-stating-maven-plugin does not use the scm information for deployment cause each artifact in your build has it's own groupId/artifactId/versions ...

Comment: "Only define the scm information in the root module of your modules." Great! Can you provide an authoritative reference on that, or any indication others agree with you? "[A]s far as I know..." The purpose of this ticket was to get something more definitive. :) If you find some documentation or something, let me know, thanks.

Comment: You can check the "Performing a Release Deployment" section of the SonaType documentation at https://central.sonatype.org/pages/apache-maven.html#nexus-staging-maven-plugin-for-deployment-and-release which says "...This process is completely independent from your workflow with your SCM system. If you want to ensure that a specific version in the Central Repository corresponds to a specific revisions in your SCM system, which is a good practice, you can either perform the commits manually in a flow similar to...or you can automate it with a script...or you can use the Maven release plugin"

Comment: I found some related discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/q/20513744/421049 . See answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/48492290/421049 .

Comment: "Only define the scm information in the root module of your modules." @khmarbaise Please explain this. If each subproject is published to Maven Central as a separate JAR, it will have erroneous SCM information information in its POM. And if " the nexus-stating-maven-plugin does not use the scm information for deployment", then why does Sonatype require the SCM information to be present?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your initial question in the title: It does not use it given the code provided at [github](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-maven-plugins). When you search for 'scm' in all .java files you have zero hits. Of course they could do some weird tricks like building the String like `"s" + "c" + "m"` or it is hidden in some third party dependency or...
Still I think besides an offical answer, this is the best any outsider can tell.